# Jumping insect acceleration question

Tags: homework-and-exercises, kinematics

From my book, verbatim:

> The froghopper, *Philaenus spumarius* is supposedly the best jumper in the animal kingdom. To start a jump, this insect can accerate at 4.00 $\mathrm{km/s^2}$ over a distance of 2.00 $\mathrm{mm}$ as it straightens its specially adapted "jumping legs." Assume the acceleration is constant. **(a)** Find the upward velocity with which the insect takes off. **(b)** In what time interval does it reach this velocity? **(c)** How high would the insect jump if air resistance were negligible? The actual height it reaches is 70 $\mathrm{cm}$, so air resistance must be  noticeable force on the leaping froghopper.

I don't feel like the book has given me enough information, though I am asked to derive $v_0$, $\Delta t$, and $\Delta y$. I don't think I'm supposed to use the $70 cm$ height given at the end of the question, because that is an experimental height and I am looking for the theoretical. Any of the kinematic equations I look for **[I'm]** missing a variable, and the equations can be quickly found here:

http://physics.info/equations/

I don't know if I should assume the bug jumps straight up, but since it has been seen to jump 70 cm high only to move 2 mm over I would imagine so.

I also think that I should include the acceleration due to gravity on the Earth, -9.81 m/s^2, so with the accelerations added would total 4000 + -9.81 = 3990.19 m/s^2, but that doesn't seem to help.

Any ideas or the solution would be helpful. Thanks in advance

Comment: One of the equations in your link (under "equations of motion") will work nicely if you think about what $v_0$ is when an insect is jumping.  Presumably, the insect begins the jump at rest, right?

Comment: I guess I was thinking the bug would start out with an initial velocity greater than zero because he needs to kick himself up. I mean when it hits the ground you don't say he lands with a velocity of zero right?

Comment: Why is there a down vote?

Comment: It seems like you're using a different definition of "initial".  "Initial velocity" as in before the bug has accelerated at all - at the very beginning of the motion.

Comment: I've seen problems in my book where a ball is thrown and the problems always gives an initial velocity greater than zero (e.g. 20 m/s). How is this different? (I'm not arguing, this just surprises me).

Comment: Ohhh I think I see. The ball-thrower had to swing his arm (holding the ball) before they released it. Before the release would be the initial velocity?

Comment: A typical physics problem like this involves the motion of an object over a particular time interval.  What the velocity of the object is at the beginning of the time interval is entirely up to the person who designed the problem.  In this problem, it's a little ambiguous, but it seems likely the person who wrote the problem intended you to imagine that the insect is sitting still before beginning the jump; thus the initial velocity is zero.  You'd have to post the text of the ball throwing problem for me to comment on the initial velocity in that case.

Comment: The "over a distance of 2.00 mm" doesn't mean over to one side;  it means that the bug moves 2.00 mm while it's legs are extending...

Comment: In ball throwing problem, the initial velocity was gave explicitly. I hope I don't have to write the whole problem to get my idea across.

Comment: @User58220 oh I didn't catch that. thanks I didn't read it clearly enough

Comment: If the bug had run and then jumped, there would be a initial velocity greater than 0, right?

Comment: @User58220 Hmm I still think the 2 mm is the Δx. I don't think how it extends it legs makes a difference, and it's the variable we need to find the final velocity. Plus I looked up pictures of the bug and it's legs are short, not like a grasshopper.

Comment: *If the bug had run and then jumped, there would be a initial velocity greater than 0, right?*  Yes, although only if it ran vertically upwards.  If it ran horizontally, then jumped vertically, then the initial speed *in the vertical direction* would still be zero.

Comment: I don't understand the hold. Could anybody tell me why this is on hold?

Comment: why was this closed?...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you already stated all you need to solve the problem. You just need to write it out.

One would normally assume the insect jumps at an angle, but given none is specified, I think it is safe to say it jumps vertically. Given the assumption that the acceleration is constant you can find the final velocity with the following formula (with null initial velocity) found on the webpage you linked:

$$
v_{f}^{2}=2\cdot a\cdot\Delta x
$$

The value of $\Delta x$ is the 2mm specified (convert it to meters so that you'll end up getting SI units). Just like when you crouch a little and then you push against the floor when jumping, and you elevate yourself while pushing with your feet before finally jumping, so does the insect, but only 2mm.

Take care to use the correct units. Just make sure that they're the same on both sides of the equation.

With the final velocity calculated you can find the time it takes the insect to reach it knowing it grows linearly with time (since the acceleration is constant), therefore:

$$v_f=(2a\Delta x)^{\frac{1}{2}}=0+a\cdot t$$

To find the maximum theoretical height you can use kinematics equations of you can just use the conservation of energy since we ignore the air drag. If we consider the potential energy to be 0 at the ground level then:

$$\frac{1}{2}mv^{2} + 0 = 0 + mgh_{max}$$

You can solve for the height by yourself. Note that the final velocity before is the initial velocity now.

On the question of what acceleration you should use, you're not wrong going with the difference between the mean acceleration and gravity but it's not entirely wrong to neglect gravity either. If you compare the two you'll see that 4000m per second squared is much greater than 9.8 m/s^2 (gravity) so you will get very similar values.

I hope you found this helpful.

Answer (score 0):

The book has given enough information, and all the required equations appear on the link you provided.

For simplicity, and also because is precise enough, you can assume the initial acceleration as the one given, i.e. not considering the effect of gravity. So the starts an accelerated movement over a distance of $2mm$ with acceleration $4.0km/s^2$ (remember to use the same units in your calculations).

The final velocity will be given by equation $v^2=v_0^2+2a(x-x_0)$ bearing in mind that initial position and velocity can be taken as zero. You are considering there that the jump is completely vertical.

The time over which this occurs, i.e. covering $2mm$ with such acceleration is extracted from $x=x_0+v_ot+1/2at^2$, found in your link.

Finally, the height can be obtained in two ways:

1) **Kinematic**: From the moment the jumping force ends, the movement continues as an accelerated one, where gravity is pulling contrary to the movement, so the previous equation $v^2=v_0^2+2a(x-x_0)$ with the proper acceleration, null final speed and initial speed as the already obtained final speed of the jump, will give you the height reached.

2) **Energetic**: The initial speed, or final speed of the jump, will give you the initial kinetic energy, which will completely turn into gravitational potential energy, so you can equate both and find the height $\Delta h$. Although the mass appears in both, when you equate them it will disappear since both depend on it in the same way.